# Good enterprise level network/server monitor

Tags: networking, monitoring

Looking for some software to help monitor the network for router/switch and server outages, and send email alerts when problems happen.  If it could help show traffic patterns and potential nodes with excessive broadcasts that would be a bonus.

I would like to have a jump on the users discovering major issues (i.e. "Is the internet down?")

Anyone in love with Orion or What's up Gold?

Answer (score 6):

Nagios is another monitoring application that is in wide use.

Comment: Couple Nagios with MRTG (or similar) and all requirements are met.

Answer (score 3):

[nagios](http://nagios.org) works well for [goldman sachs](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-2694482537942655203#).. ; check also [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Re: Splunk - if you're looking for a "pure" or classic network / device monitoring setup, then Splunk may not be what you're looking for. But it certainly can be (and is) used that way - some customers have dumped Patrol, OV, nagios and other monitoring tools for splunk. As for difficulty with setup, yeah it varies, depending on what you want to monitor.

For those who have chosen Splunk, it comes down to being able to do more than monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally used OpenNMS http://www.opennms.org/ with good results. It has both monitor (resource graphs) and alert capabilities.

Many say that it scales very well.

I do not need this tool any more, but I would try Icinga http://www.icinga.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check out Splunk.  It is a very flexible tool that can monitor about anything you could want.  At the very least, I know that it can perform as you have specified.

Comment: Splunk is not a real monitoring tool in the sense the asker is looking for.

Comment: Well, yes it is.  It is just that Nagios or Zappix is more "out of the box."

Answer (score 0):

Splunk is a bear to setup, didn't find it that helpful compared to:

Zenoss with snmp monitoring

-or-

Nagios.

Xymon/bigbrother is a good monitor too.

Answer (score 0):

I a big nagios fan, but at work we use opsview http://www.opsview.com/community. It is basically nagios with a great web ui (you can do almost everything from the ui), optional commercial support and nice stuff like mrtg, nagvis, nmis and replicated monitoring support included in their community edition out of the box.

They have packages for red hat, debian, ubuntu, solaris 10 and, of course, you can build it from sources if you want. They also have a virtual appliance (vmware) to get yourself started in no time.

All the nagios plugins you can write/download from the nagios exchange(s) sites you can use with opsview.

We have been using it for over one year now and are very satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

i like hyperic hq. it records stats so you can see how things have performed historically. there's a free community edition too.